# how to reset form group array in angular

Tags: angular

I have a form array, but if I push another form this have setted the validations of previus form.

in this example `[https://plnkr.co/edit/ApCn3YicMjfm2vhSOudj?p=preview][1]`https://plnkr.co/edit/ApCn3YicMjfm2vhSOudj?p=preview you can see that the second form shows the name validation, how can I solve this?

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: if you fill the form and submit you could see that the second form has the validations of the first one, it shows the message 'name valid' I want to reset the second, third and others forms to not show the validations of others

Comment: I think you need  a blank form when submit ,right?

Comment: yes, the new form has to be blank

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above and messing around with the plunker I think I finally see what you are asking.

The issue has to do with how forms work.

Forms have two pieces:

1) The form element itself displayed in the view.

2) The form data structure, which for reactive forms as you have are defined in the component code with the `this.user` variable. It is this data structure that tracks the forms values and validity state.

In looking at your code your ngFor is creating multiple form elements (#1 above) but using the *same* form data structure (#2 above). So the multiple forms will always show the same values and have the same validation state.

You'd need to build a formArray and create an entry in that array for every "form" you create.

I have an example of a form array here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms

Answer (score 0):

All the forms share the same FormGroup here,named "user",which kept form data and states ,so you can either create a separate FormGroup for each Form or reset the value of "user" each time in the submit method,but the latter will make the current form lost its data either.Cause they shared the "user".

```
onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: User, valid: boolean }) {
console.log(value, valid);
this.data.push(value)
this.user = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
  account: this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    confirm: ['', Validators.required]
  })
});
console.log(this.data)
```

}